# Parsing CSV file using Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have been using matplotlib for quite some time now and it is great however, I want to switch to panda and my first attempt at it didn't go so well.

My data set looks like this:

```
sam,123,184,2.6,543
winter,124,284,2.6,541
summer,178,384,2.6,542
summer,165,484,2.6,544
winter,178,584,2.6,545
sam,112,684,2.6,546
zack,145,784,2.6,547
mike,110,984,2.6,548
etc.....
```

I want first to search the csv for anything with the name mike and create it own list. Now with this list I want to be able to do some math for example add `sam[3] + winter[4]` or `sam[1]/10`. The last part would be to plot it columns against each other.

Going through this page

```
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table
```

The only thing I see is if I have a column header, however, I don't have any headers. I only know the position in a row of the values I want.

So my question is:

1. How do I create a bunch of list for each row (sam, winter, summer)
2. Is this method efficient if my csv has millions of data point?
3. Could I use `matplotlib` plotting to plot pandas dataframe?

ie :

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize= (10,10))
ax = fig1.add_subplot(211)
ax.plot(mike[1], winter[3], label='Mike vs Winter speed', color = 'red')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read a csv without headers:

```
data=pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None)
```

Columns will be numbered starting from 0.
Selecting and filtering:

```
all_summers = data[data[0]=='summer']
```

If you want to do some operations grouping by the first column, it will look like this:

```
data.groupby(0).sum()
data.groupby(0).count()
...
```

Selecting a row after grouping:

```
sums = data.groupby(0).sum()
sums.loc['sam']
```

Plotting example:

```
 sums.plot()
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.show()
```

For more details about plotting, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/visualization.html

Comment: I am a bit confused. Where in here shows how I can create a list based on the first column value? for example a list where all it contains is summer?

Comment: You get all `summer`s like this `data[data[0]=='summer']`

Comment: That didn't work here is what I have tired: Sam=data[data[0]=='sam']
print (Sam) , all i got was expected 10 fields, saw 15 skipping line 3

Comment: Where are you getting this error? It looks like an error you would get while reading the csv file..

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None)
mike = df[df[0]=='mike'].values.tolist()
winter = df[df[0]=='winter'].values.tolist()
```

Then you can plot those list as you wanted to above

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize= (10,10))

ax = fig1.add_subplot(211)

ax.plot(mike, winter, label='Mike vs Winter speed', color = 'red')
```

Comment: I am also getting an error of Expected 10 fields saw 15 skipping line 3 and so on.

Comment: It's likely because you have different lengths of lists.  Try comparing ``len(winter)`` and ``len(mike)``

Comment: Yes they are different. I guess I don't have a true csv file since I have spaces after each comma?

Comment: .csv files usually have a space after the comma.  Your issue is that you have a different number of entries for each category.  Also your scatter plot will vary with the order that your data is sorted even if you forced them to the same length.