# How can I parse my CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hello,

My CSV file looks like this:

```
A,B,C,D
12,22000,"3,9","8,5"
```

I want read that with:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep = ',', decimal=',', quoting=3, engine='python')
```

The result gives a dataframe with the correct first line, but the second is concentrated in the first column. Well it parses the first line but the second is not. I think that quotes are responsible. Do you have an idea?
Thank you.

Best regards

SR

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing CSV file using Panda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666589/parsing-csv-file-using-panda)

Comment: I don't see how they're duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default quoting behaviour should work fine:

```
In [7]: !cat test.csv
A,B,C,D
12,22000,"3,9","8,5"

In [8]: pd.read_csv('test.csv', decimal=',', sep=',')
Out[8]:
    A      B    C    D
0  12  22000  3.9  8.5
```

Comment: It works !! thank you ...it had reverse 'decimal' and 'sep'.

Comment: @StefReyes That wasn't the problem. The arguments can be specified in any order.